# How is std::erase implemented for vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, iterator

I have a custom Vec class, duplicating the functionality of std::vector, but I am unable to implement an erase function which takes the same parameters as the standard library implementation (and handles them elegantly). Specifically, in C++11, [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) has the signature `iterator erase (const_iterator position);`, where the returned iterator points to the new position of the element after the element deleted. My only solution is to pass a non-const iterator, copy all the elements after the given iterator back one position with a second iterator, and use a third iterator to store the original pointer position. This requires three non-const iterator.

```
template <class T> typename Vec<T>::iterator Vec<T>::erase(iterator it)
{
    iterator copy_iterator = it; // used to shift elements one position to the left past the deleted element.

    iterator return_iterator = it; // holds original it position, per std implementation

    while (it != (this -> end() - 1)) { // copies elements one position left
        *copy_iterator++ = *++it;
    }

    alloc.destroy(it); // destroy last element in vector

    avail = it; // shortens the vector by 1

    return return_iterator;
}
```

Here avail is the iterator which points one past the end of the vector, i.e. `iterator end() { return avail; }`. I don't see how any such function could take a const_iterator if it has to shift every element left by one, and I really don't like having three iterators. Is there a better solution?

**Additional Standards Question:**

[Up until C++98](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/), vector::erase took an iterator parameter. I am curious why this standard was changed. In C++11, the erase functions includes what looks a direct conversion from const_iterator to iterator without any further explanation for why it is now const.

```
template <class T> typename vector<T>::iterator erase(const_iterator __position) {
    difference_type __ps = __position - cbegin();
    pointer __p = this->__begin_ + __ps;
    iterator __r = __make_iter(__p);
    this->__destruct_at_end(_VSTD::move(__p + 1, this->__end_, __p));
    return __r;
}
```

*Here is a partial implementation of the Vec class:*

```
template <class T> class Vec {
public:
    // typedefs

    Vec() { create(); }

    explicit Vec(std::size_t n, const T& val = T()) { create(n, val); }

    Vec(const Vec& v) { create(v.begin(), v.end()); } // copy constructor
    Vec& operator=(const Vec&);
    ~Vec() { uncreate(); } // destructor

    T& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }

    void push_back(const T& val) {
        if (avail == limit)
            grow();
        unchecked_append(val);
    }

    size_type size() const { return avail - data; }

    iterator begin() { return data; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return data; }

    iterator end() { return avail; }
    const_iterator end() const { return avail; }

    iterator erase(iterator);

private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;

    allocator<T> alloc;

    void create();
    void create(size_type, const T&);
    void create(const_iterator, const_iterator); // calls alloc.allocate, then copies without default initialization

    void uncreate(); // calls alloc.destroy on everything, then deallocates

    void grow(); // allocates twice the memory
    void unchecked_append(const T&);
};
```

Comment: those variable names are probably going to make the task more confusing.

Comment: I've updated the variables names to be more readable and added some comments. Let me know if I should change anything else.

Comment: Your vector should internally be an array... so what is `alloc` doing?

Comment: @Charles I am handling the memory manually using an allocator class from `<memory>` to avoid default initialization of vector elements. I have added a partial implementation (this follows Koenig Accelerated C++).

Comment: 1) Don't reinvent the wheel. 2) Instead of asking how to implement it, why not look at the source code of STL.

Comment: The source for libc++ is available here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx

Comment: You know you can convert a const iterator to a non-const one, right

Comment: @M.M Yes, but I don't understand why you would. Is there a reason why the std library implementation would take a const_iterator parameter, and then immediately convert it, especially since it does change the memory to which it's pointing?

Comment: @JAustin: In regards to your question about why the parameter type of the erase function was changed, it was because it makes usage of the function more convenient. An `iterator` is implicitly convertible to a `const_iterator`, but the reverse is not true. So by changing the parameter to `const_iterator`, now you can pass both an `iterator` or a `const_iterator`, whereas before you could only pass an `iterator`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I apologize if this is a stupid question, and you addressed it partly in your answer, but isn't the whole point of const_iterators to ensure that they aren't used to modify the memory they point to? Clearly erase isn't const, but isn't this still kind of misleading behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of a `const_iterator`. But we're not really using the `const_iterator` to modify the container. We're using the `erase` function. The iterator is just used so that the `erase` function can identify the position of the element. Whether it's misleading or not is a matter of opinion, but I don't think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert your `const_iterator` to an `iterator` within the function. Now, normally, this would be a no-no. But since we know that the `Vec` is not const (because `erase` is a non-const function), this is safe, unless the user passes an iterator that doesn't belong to the `Vec` (which is not safe regardless).

So, how to get a non-const `iterator` from a `const_iterator`? You could implement a private member in your `const_iterator` class to do this and make the `Vec` class a friend. But since we're dealing with random access iterators, that is not necessary since we can just use iterator arithmetic.

```
// given a const_iterator cit
iterator it = begin() + (cit - begin());
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the best answer to this but from what I can see you could re-derive a *non-const* pointer/iterator to the erase position using pointer arithmetic or do a legal `const_cast` secure in the knowledge that your array is actually real (was created `non-const`) because erase is a *non-const* function and could not be called on a const object.

```
template <class T> typename Vec<T>::iterator Vec<T>::erase(const_iterator it)
{
    iterator non_const_it = this->begin() + std::distance(this->cbegin(), it);

    iterator copy_iterator = non_const_it;

    // etc...

    return non_const_it;
}
```